# How to effectively split grouped records into batches

Tags: sql, t-sql

For each group in table I need to split that group into specific amount of records (batches) and mark each record in batch with according batch id.

Right now, my implementation based on cursors is IMHO clumsy. It takes 1 minute to split set of 10 000 rows which is, needless to say, very slow. Any clues how to make that work faster?

Here is test script.

```
 -- Needed to generate big data
 DECLARE @Naturals TABLE (ID INT)
 INSERT INTO @Naturals (ID)
 VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)

 DECLARE @TestData TABLE
 (
    LINK INT,
    F_House INT,
    F_Batch UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
 )

 INSERT INTO @TestData (LINK, F_House)
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by T1.ID), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by T1.ID) % 5 
 FROM 
 @Naturals T1
 CROSS JOIN @Naturals T2
 CROSS JOIN @Naturals T3
 CROSS JOIN @Naturals T4
 --CROSS JOIN @Naturals T5 -- that would give us 100 000

 -- Finished preparing Data (10 000 rows)
 SELECT 'Processing:', COUNT(*) FROM @TestData

 DECLARE @batchSize INT -- That would be amount of rows in each batch
 SET @batchSize = 50

 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#G') IS NOT NULL -- Split set of data into groups. We need to create batches in each group.
    DROP TABLE #G

 SELECT 
    buf.F_House, COUNT(*) AS GroupCount
 INTO #G
 FROM @TestData buf
 GROUP BY buf.F_House -- That logic could be tricky one. Right now simplifying

 DECLARE @F_House INT -- That would be group key

 DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
 SELECT F_House
 FROM #G
 ORDER BY F_House

 OPEN db_cursor FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @F_House

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
 BEGIN 
    PRINT 'Processing house group: ' + CAST(@F_House AS VARCHAR(10))

    -- For each group let's create batches
    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TestData AS itmds 
                  WHERE itmds.F_House = @F_House 
                  AND itmds.F_Batch IS NULL
                )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @batchLink UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
        SET @batchLink = NEWID()

        UPDATE itmds
        SET itmds.F_Batch = @batchLink
        FROM @TestData AS itmds
        WHERE itmds.F_House = @F_House 
                  AND itmds.F_Batch IS NULL
                  AND itmds.LINK IN 
                  (
                        SELECT TOP (@batchSize)
                        sub.LINK
                        FROM @TestData sub
                        WHERE sub.F_House = @F_House
                        AND sub.F_Batch IS NULL
                  )

    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @F_House
 END 

 CLOSE db_cursor   
 DEALLOCATE db_cursor

 SELECT
    buf.F_House, COUNT(distinct F_Batch) AS BatchCountInHouse
 FROM @TestData buf
 GROUP BY buf.F_House
 ORDER BY buf.F_House
```

**Expected output (considering batchsize = 50)**

10 000 rows / 5 houses = 2000 rows/house

2000 rows/house / 50(batchSize) = 40 batches/house

[image]

Comment: you should show some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: My test script in post generates all test data. Just copy-paste it, execute and it will do all work

Comment: yes..but how can we understand the output you are trying to get?

Comment: I see. I'll add expected output.

Answer (score 2):

I would use an inner looping inside of a looping referencing a grouping level. 
 Then you can iterate through from the grouping down into the BatchGrouping.  However as you pointed out speed is an issue with table variables and CTE's for that reason I in this case tested with a tempdb # table.  This way I could index after the insert and optimize performance.  I can run a million rows of aggregation logic in about 16 seconds.  I consider that acceptable performance.  But my Dev Box is an I7 6700, with 16 gigs of DDR4, and an SSD.  Performance times may vary based on hardware obviously.

```
--Make up some fake data for example
DECLARE 
  @Start INT = 1
, @End INT = 100000
;

SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE tempdb..#Temp

CREATE Table #Temp (Id INT, Grp int, Val VARCHAR(8), BatchGroup int)

WHILE @Start <= @End
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Temp (Id, Grp, Val) 
    VALUES (@Start, CAST(RAND() * 8 AS INT) + 1, LEFT(NEWID(), 8))

    SELECT @Start += 1;  
END

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Temp_Grp ON #Temp(Grp, BatchGroup)

--Determine Batch Size You want for groupings
DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 1000;

--Let's randomly mess with groupings
DECLARE @X INT = 1
WHILE @X <= 4
BEGIN
    ; WITH x AS 
      (
      SELECT TOP (@BatchSize * 4) 
        Id
      , Grp
      , Val
      FROM #Temp
      WHERE Grp = CAST(RAND() * 8 AS INT) + 1
      )
    UPDATE x
    SET Grp = CAST(RAND() * 8 AS INT) + 1

    SELECT @X += 1
END

DECLARE 
  @CurrentGroup INT = 1
, @CurrentBatch INT = 1

WHILE @CurrentGroup <= (SELECT MAX(Grp) FROM #Temp) -- Exists (SELECT 1 FROM @Temp WHERE BatchGroup IS NULL)
BEGIN
    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Temp WHERE Grp = @CurrentGroup AND BatchGroup IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        ; WITH x AS 
        (
        SELECT TOP (@BatchSize) *
        FROM #Temp
        WHERE Grp = @CurrentGroup 
          AND BatchGroup IS NULL
        )
        update x
        SET BatchGroup = @CurrentBatch

        SELECT @CurrentBatch += 1;
    END

    SELECT @CurrentBatch = 1
    SELECT @CurrentGroup += 1;
END

--Proof
Select 
  Grp
, COUNT(DISTINCT Id)
, COUNT(DISTINCT BatchGroup)
From #Temp
GROUP BY Grp
```

Comment: Ideally you would do this FIRST before doing processing with a cursor or other loop method.  You are essentially going to prime the data for a batch size, the do some work on it, then you could have an additional column or such to mark as complete when done.  I have done this before for slow running processes that trying to do work on a full dataset of over millions of records would not be feasible.

Comment: I think you oversimplified example -you don't have groups in which you need to create batches. That GroupingSize variable must be calculated in each group. And then each group must be ntiled. I thought about it and didn't find answer how to NTILE group without doing that calcualtion for each group(which means cursors again). Can you show it on my test case?

Comment: I could add a rand to do a random grouping addition to make it fall out of the bounds, then you are essentially though just doing another grouping where I would just use Ntile with a 'partition by' of the group I create though.  But I am curious when you say 'that grouping size must be calculated in each group'.  Are you meaning a dynamically changing batch size?  Wouldn't you want your batch to be uniform and just say Group1 has 2030 houses so it has three batches of 1000, Group2 has 800 houses so it only has a single batch.   it is 40 from 2000 / 50, so you are static in your example.

Comment: I mean number of rows in each group could be different. Batch size is const. How would you do partition by? In order to get number of tiles you have to divide #rows in group / batch size for each group.

Comment: I will give another update to my example to make it more complex and see if it suits your needs.  A windowed function can have an extra definition on grouping called partition by.  It is essentially an inline select statement for an aggregate using a group by which is partition by and order by which is the same name.

Comment: How would you pass ntile quantity argument if its different for each partition? Since number of rows in partition may be different.

Comment: What is a different number each time?  You use a static 50 in your example what would make it be different now.

Comment: Number of rows for each house  could be different. That "DIFFERENT" number of rows must be split into batches each having 50 rows in it. If house 0 has 20 rows then it would create one batch. House 1 has 220 rows - that would give us 5 batches.

Comment: Okay you want a fixed batch of X numbers regardless of sample size and then group that.  Is that correct?  You are correct then, NTile will not work for that, I will update in a little while.  I think your example was a set size so it confused me, sorry about that.

Comment: Updated, forget about the NTile.  I think you were on the right track with the Cursor.  I used a loop but a forward read only cursor may still be even faster if time is a major consideration.

Comment: I will change your code so that it will work with my data and measure time.

Answer (score 2):

This is set based avoiding a cursor. The assigned `F_Batch` is a BIGINT:

```
;with baseRowNum as 
 (
   SELECT LINK, F_House,
      -- row number per F_House
      Row_Number() Over (PARTITION  BY F_House ORDER BY LINK) AS rn
   FROM @TestData
 )
SELECT *,
   -- combine F_House & group number into a unique result
   F_House * 10000 +
   -- start a new sub group for every F_House or after @batchSize rows
   Sum(CASE WHEN rn % @batchSize = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   Over (ORDER BY F_House, rn 
         ROWS Unbounded Preceding) AS F_Batch
FROM baseRowNum
```

If you really need a `UNIQUEINDENTIFIER` you can join back:

```
;with baseRowNums as 
 (
   SELECT LINK, F_House,
      -- row number per F_House
      Row_Number() Over (PARTITION  BY F_House ORDER BY LINK) AS rn
   FROM @TestData
 )
,batchNums as
 (
   SELECT *,
      -- combine F_House & group number into a unique result
      F_House * 10000 +
      -- start a new sub group for every F_House or after @batchSize rows
      Sum(CASE WHEN rn % @batchSize = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      Over (ORDER BY F_House, rn 
            ROWS Unbounded Preceding) AS F_Batch
   FROM baseRowNums
 )
,GUIDs as
 (
   select F_Batch, MAX(newid()) as GUID
   from batchNums
   group by F_Batch
 )
-- select * from
--from batchNums join GUIDs 
--  on batchNums.F_Batch = GUIDs.F_Batch
select F_House, GUID, count(*)
from batchNums join GUIDs 
  on batchNums.F_Batch = GUIDs.F_Batch
group by F_House, GUID
order by F_House, count(*) desc
```

See [Fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=2fa8ba86352c5ead604a813dd5d41088).

Comment: Can you show how to get expected result? I don't understand how can I update TestData Table so that it will store F_Batch in it.

Comment: @nikita: You Update from this Select using the PK, probably `LINK`

Comment: If i do this http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=e97c53f413bb10b88e13523fcf2808cf then query is executing for eternity

Comment: @nikita: Don't now, better try it on your own server.

Comment: I did. Result is the same.

Comment: @nikita: Strange, check the plan. Try to materialize the Select in another temp table before updating.

Comment: Did it. http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=6a4f2ad822a38c5b0c790fe85ae51479. Results (on my machine):10 000   - 0 sec
100 000  - 3sec
1 000 000  - 50sec
10 000 000  - 570sec

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've tried NTILE() with cursors and it's quite fast(I mean its faster then 1 minute for 10 000 rows). 
10 000 rows for 0 seconds.

100 000 rows for 3 seconds.

1 000 000 rows for 34 seconds.

10 000 000 rows for 6 minutes

Linear grow in complexity which is nice.

```
     -- Needed to generate big data
 DECLARE @Naturals TABLE (ID INT)
 INSERT INTO @Naturals (ID)
 VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)

 DECLARE @TestData TABLE
 (
    LINK INT,
    F_House INT,
    F_Batch UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
 )

 INSERT INTO @TestData (LINK, F_House)
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by T1.ID), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by T1.ID) % 5 
 FROM 
 @Naturals T1
 CROSS JOIN @Naturals T2
 CROSS JOIN @Naturals T3
 CROSS JOIN @Naturals T4
 --CROSS JOIN @Naturals T5 -- that would give us 100 000

 -- Finished preparing Data (10 000 rows)
 SELECT 'Processing:', COUNT(*) FROM @TestData

 DECLARE @batchSize INT -- That would be amount of rows in each batch
 SET @batchSize = 50

 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#G') IS NOT NULL -- Split set of data into groups. We need to create batches in each group.
    DROP TABLE #G

 SELECT 
    buf.F_House, COUNT(*) AS GroupCount
 INTO #G
 FROM @TestData buf
 GROUP BY buf.F_House -- That logic could be tricky one. Right now simplifying

 DECLARE @F_House INT -- That would be group key



 DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
 SELECT F_House
 FROM #G
 ORDER BY F_House

 OPEN db_cursor FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @F_House

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
 BEGIN 
    PRINT 'Processing house group: ' + CAST(@F_House AS VARCHAR(10))

    DECLARE @rowsInGroup INT
    SELECT @rowsInGroup = COUNT(*) FROM @TestData
    WHERE F_House = @F_House

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TileBatch') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #TileBatch

    SELECT 
        T.[NTile], NEWID() AS F_Batch
    INTO #TileBatch
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT distinct
            NTILE(@rowsInGroup / @batchSize) OVER (ORDER BY LINK) AS [NTile]
        from 
            @TestData
        WHERE F_House = @F_House
    ) T

    UPDATE D
    SET D.F_Batch = B.F_Batch
    FROM
    @TestData D
        INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            *, NTILE(@rowsInGroup / @batchSize) OVER (ORDER BY LINK) AS [NTile]
        from 
            @TestData
        WHERE F_House = @F_House
    ) DT ON D.LINK = DT.LINK
        INNER JOIN
    #TileBatch B ON DT.[NTile] = B.[NTile]
    WHERE D.F_House = @F_House

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @F_House
 END 

 CLOSE db_cursor   
 DEALLOCATE db_cursor

 SELECT
    buf.F_House, COUNT(distinct F_Batch) AS BatchCountInHouse
 FROM @TestData buf
 GROUP BY buf.F_House
 ORDER BY buf.F_House
```

Comment: Where do you see exponential growth? Looks quite linear to me (besides the 10,000 rows, but this might be due to data fitting in cache)

Comment: I updated my example if you want to take a look.  You are correct on the issue of the increasing load as the set grows.